# CSS in an external file not being applied

Tags: asp.net, html, css

I've read some similar issues here, but no answer they provided could help me.

I have a small asp.net page for study porpuses:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" 

Inherits="Site.Default" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/Landing.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="loginHeader" class="aaa">
        <div>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtUsername" runat="server"/>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtPassword" runat="server"/>
            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Login" OnClick="btnLogin_Click" />
            <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Register" OnClick="btnRegister_Click" />
            <br />
            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Password not valid" Visible="False"/>
        </div>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see, the css/landing CSS file is being added.
Here is this css file:

```
#loginHeader 
{
display:block;
background-color:Blue;
}

.aaa
{
    display:block;
    background-color:Red;
}
```

If I open the page, no style is applied. Firebug shows that the css is being downloaded.
If I move the css markup to the page, inside a  tag, it works, if I change back to the css file, it stops working.

Do you see any reason for this behavior?

Thanks,
Oscar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Just found it out: there was an error on my config file, which defined that the user should be logged in to access the css files...
solved, thanks :)

Comment: Drag the CSS file from Solution Explorer into the head tag in code view ;-)

Comment: Just did it. The problem was that the user had no permission to access the css folder ;)

Answer (score 0):

You have written the link tag this way.

```
<link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/Landing.css" />
```

Make it

```
<link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/Landing.css" />
```

This will instruct the browser to look for the "Landing.css" file inside the css directory.

Comment: Well this is a different thing. Path without a leading slash means relative path. If you are currently in, say, http://foo.bar/Products/Default.aspx then it will look for Landing.css in the directory http://foo.bar/Products/css/Landing.css. If there is a leading slash it means an absolute path and will follow http://foo.bar/css/Landing.css no matter what is the current location. The latter, i.e. with a leading slash is much more preferable.